# Icon of all file types that open with vscode has changed to one icon

Tags: windows, windows-10, icons, visual-studio-code, regedit

I wanted to change default icons for .py .cpp .c using [FileTypeMan](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html#:%7E:text=FileTypesMan%20is%20an%20alternative%20to,%2C%20Browser%20Flags%2C%20and%20more.). But after that, the icons of all of them became the same because the default app for these extensions was vscode.
I tried to fix it using regedit ([How to Assign a Custom Icon to a File Type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-assign-a-custom-icon-to-a-file-type)) but nothing has changed.

Link of screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4cjK.png

I would appreciate any help to change this to default icons or separated icons for each file type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how, but somehow it has been fixed.
It was neither restart nor cache cleaning. I think it was being fixed by vscode while I was using it.